# CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability object is not disposed along all exception paths

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, fxcop

I am getting code analysis error in the below method.

```
    public static OracleCommand CreateStoredProcedureCommand(string name,
                                                             OracleConnection connection)
    {
        return new OracleCommand(name, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
    }
```

> CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method
>   'StoredProcedureHelper.CreateStoredProcedureCommand(string,
>   OracleConnection)', object 'command' is not disposed along all
>   exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'command'
>   before all references to it are out of scope

how can it this be resolved without suppressing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object is not disposed, when the assignment to the property throws an exception. Try this:

```
public static OracleCommand CreateStoredProcedureCommand(string name,
                                                         OracleConnection connection)
{
    OracleCommand result = new OracleCommand(name, connection);
    try
    {
        result.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        result.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't, looking at the method, the responsibility for disposing of the object must always lie with the caller.

You will have to suppress it.

Comment: As Henrik says, there is a possibility for the property setter to throw an exception leaving the object undisposed.